# Functions - Simple Surjection

Tags: functions

$s : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $s(x)$ = $x^2$.

In this instance why is the function $s$ not onto?

Comment: because s(1)=s(-1)=1 - two answers to 'if s(x)=1, what is x?'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry  You just explained why the function is not injective (one-to-one).  The question is asking why the function is not surjective (onto), meaning that there is a real number that is not in the range.

Comment: i know, just testing - whats bijective - onto-to-onto?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry They usually write it out as one-one and onto. I have no idea why one wouldn't use the much clearer terms injective, surjective and bijective though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s$ being "onto" means for all $x\in\mathbb R$ there is a $y$ s.t. $s(y)=x$.  If $x<0$ then no such $y$ exists.  Therefore $s$ cannot be onto.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  What real number has square $-1$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm  agree with your answer. If you select a negative number then there is no valu in the domain so that $s(x)=y$